# How do you use background: auto; correctly?

Tags: html, css, background

I'm trying to make the background fill the whole page. The only way I figured out how to do it is by setting the height and width of `<div id="All">` and putting that div around everything else. I know that if I change the size of the browser, though, it won't auto resize, so it would look weird if I made my browser smaller or bigger.

If I set height and width to auto on #All, it def doesn't fill out the whole webpage. Please advise what I am doing wrong. Plus if I do auto, the sticky #Move doesn't stay at the top of the page.

This code is just stuff I have learned, so not an actual project, but I want to learn how to do it for future projects.

```css
#Move {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  color: red;
}

h1 {
  color: red;
}

.Hello {
  font-size: 36px;
}

.Hello2 {
  font-size: 15px;
}

p {
  color: white;
}

.DivClass {
  width: 160px;
  height: 220px;
  padding: 40px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-radius: 60px;
  margin: 50px;
  background: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSqOq9_iT948LTPmS5FuCMlaqlvn2KJQ-0d7Xw5kLMfWz69wwRA&usqp=CAU");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 80%;
}

.image-whitecat {
  width: 500px;
  heigth: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 50px 50px 90px 250px;
  transform: rotate(10deg);
}

.image-cat {
  width: 700px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 300px;
  margin-left: 350px;
  filter: opacity(70%)
}

.Purple {
  color: purple;
}

.PurpleText {
  background: teal;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 1000px;
}

#All {
  background-color: lavender;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  height: 1850px;
  width: 1810px;
}
```

```html
<div id="All">
  <div class="DivClass">
    <h1>HELLO!!!</h1>
    <p class="Hello">Hello</p>
    <p class="Hello2">Hello 2</p>
    <p>Yes</p>
  </div>
  <p id="Move">I will stay at the top of the page!</p>
  <div>
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/11/30/14/11/kitty-551554__340.jpg" class="image-whitecat" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/28/12/35/cat-1285634__340.png" class="image-cat" />
  </div>
  <div class="PurpleText">
    <p class="Purple">Purple</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note you have a typo in `heigth: 500px;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will need to give both your html and body tags a css height ...

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

So, 
https://jsfiddle.net/z51crou7/